# How to create colour map from 3 arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, colormap

I'm trying to create a colour plot in python of two arrays t1 and t2 with the colours being set by a third one v, but I can't get the colour bar to be in terms of the v array, it is instead in terms of t1. This is my code:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    t1 = [75, 76, 77, 78]
    t2 = [75, 76, 77, 78]
    v = [0.5, 0.5, 0.8, 0.8]

    image_data = np.column_stack([t1, t2, v])
    plt.imshow(image_data)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
```

It produces this figure:
[image: Colour map with incorrect colour bar]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `plt.imshow()` plots a 2d array (an image), but you have three 1d arrays. So how should they be plotted?

Comment: t1 should be on the x axis and t2 should be on the y axis, and v is the value of each point on the plot that should correspond to the colours

Comment: Your arrays `t1` and `t2` have 4 values each. An image of 4 x 4 values contains 16 pixels. However your `v` array only has 4 values. So either you do not want an image plot or you need to tell us how they should be plotted.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `imshow` to set x and y coordinates, and color as 3rd.
It is to show a matrix image, where there are X*Y values, and all these values represent color.
Perhaps you want to use `scatter`.
E.g. you can try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t1 = [0,1,2,3]
t2 = [0, 10, 20, 30]
v = [0.5, 0.5, 0.8, 0.8]

plt.scatter(t1, t2, c=v, cmap='Greens')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

You can check which colormap is most suitable for you.